# How to create list from loop?

Tags: python

How to create list from loop?

I have got list:

```
my_dict = dict()
my_list = ["aaa", "bbb"]
for el im my_list:
    #
```

I want to add to `my_dict` element with name from loop, to get in `my_dict`:

`{"aaa": [], 'bbb':[]}`

Comment: `{i: [] for i in my_list}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my_dict = dict()
my_list = ["aaa", "bbb"]
for el in my_list:
    my_dict[el] = []

print (my_dict)
```

output:

```
{'aaa': [], 'bbb': []}
```

or use list comprehension:

```
my_dict = dict()
my_list = ["aaa", "bbb"]

print ({el:[] for el in my_list})
```

output:

```
{'aaa': [], 'bbb': []}
```

Answer (score 1):

If my_dict is already existing dict and you want to add more items to that then you can use the below code

```
my_dict.update({key:[] for key in my_list})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think so:

```
my_dict = dict()
my_list = ["aaa", "bbb"]
for el in my_list:
    my_dict[el] = []

print(my_dict)
```